# Is there a way to get around the inability to add measures as constant lines for Power BI scatter plots?

Tags: graph, powerbi, constants

So I'd like to use a calculated or referenced value from another table as a y constant line in Power BI. I know there's no default way of doing it but I was wondering if there was a workaround. I have this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

The key is how to I get it to reference a value in another table or calculated column as that constant line since adding a measure isn't a feature right now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add another chart (Line and Stacked Column Chart), include your metric in line values. Remove the background, changed to off the X and Y axis.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there would be an alternative to this if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use R or Python visual.

In that case, make sure to define the measure for horizontal line to ignore the filter context of X-axis dimension (use `ALLSELECTED`).

Answer (score 0):

With this table (`Tabell`):

```
X   Y   Z
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
```

And this measure: `Measure = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Tabell[X]);ALLSELECTED(Tabell))+1`

A scatter plot with a constant line that always is on `average of X+1` can be created with this Python-script:

```
# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(X, Y, Z)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Klistra in eller skriv in din skriptkod här:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# zorder is to make the dots above the grid
ax.scatter(dataset.Y, dataset.X, s=dataset.Z*100, c='grey',zorder=10)

# this shows a constant line between (0,Measure) and (10,Measure)
ax.plot([0,10],[max(dataset.Measure), max(dataset.Measure)], c='r', linestyle='--')

# this is to set the limit of the axes so the horisontal line doesnt decide the chart size
ax.set_xlim([0,6])

# to set the ticks yourself
ax.set_yticks(range(0,6,1))

# display a thin grid
plt.grid(True, lw=.3)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]